# Error in pmin and pmax "Error in `[.data.frame`(each, nas[, 1L]) : undefined columns selected"

Tags: r

I have dataframes df.1 and df.2 (extracts from  real data frames)

```
df.1<-structure(list(a = c(47.22, 88.89, 71.88, NA, 75, 100, 72.22, 
94.44, 52.78, 86.11, 66.67), b = c(46.88, 80.56, 80.56, NA, 31.25, 
100, 52.78, 100, 31.25, 91.67, 58.33)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = 2330:2340, class = "data.frame")

df.2<-structure(list(a = c(75, 47.22, 86.11, 93.75, 86.11, 77.78, 91.67, 
100, 38.89, 97.22, 100), b = c(71.88, 72.22, 83.33, NA, 50, 69.44, 
100, 100, 53.13, 91.67, 88.89)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = 2330:2340, class =   "data.frame")
```

Trying to apply pmin or pmax function to these data frames results in error:

```
 pmax (df.1, df.2)
 Error in `[.data.frame`(each, nas[, 1L]) : undefined columns selected
```

I have absolutely no idea why it is happening, pmax and pmin work great on other parts of my real data frames and they look quite similar to these pieces of data. I would very much appreciate your help.

Here is the session info:

```
(sessionInfo())
 R version 2.14.2 (2012-02-29)
 Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

 locale:
 [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252        LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_0.6.2    plyr_1.8         Revobase_6.1.0   RevoMods_6.1.0     RevoScaleR_3.1-0 lattice_0.20-0   rpart_3.1-51    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 foreach_1.4.0   grid_2.14.2     iterators_1.0.6 tools_2.14.2
```

Comment: I get the error on a clean session.  @DSSS please can you post your session info (sessionInfo()) - mine is a tad too long.  I do not get an error when I use `max`, could this be used as a workaround?

Comment: Thank you, I posted the session info in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting both data frames into a `matrix` before running `pmax` or `pmin`:

```
pmax(as.matrix(df.1), as.matrix(df.2))

#         a      b
# 2330  75.00  71.88
# 2331  88.89  80.56
# 2332  86.11  83.33
# 2333     NA     NA
# 2334  86.11  50.00
# 2335 100.00 100.00
# 2336  91.67 100.00
# 2337 100.00 100.00
# 2338  52.78  53.13
# 2339  97.22  91.67
# 2340 100.00  88.89
```

Source: `?pmax` "pmax and pmin take one or more vectors (or matrices) as arguments..."

Comment: Thank you very much,   Steph Locke and TWL. I use as.matrix to get the problem fixed, although I do not know the reason.

Comment: @DSSS, you're welcome. In R, vectors and matrices are used for linear algebraic operations [[ref](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Vector-arithmetic)]. Matrix can be considered as a vector with dimensions [[ref](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Other-types-of-objects)]. On the other hand data frame is a list, which can contain numeric vectors among many [[ref](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Data-frames)]. In the latter case, you would have to reference each component separately to obtain the maxima/minima, i.e. `pmax(df.1$a, df.2$a)`.

Comment: Also, see [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for further discussion. It contains many practical examples.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure (yet) how to resolve the issue, but it appears to be surrounding NAs appearing within the first dataset being compared.  You can confirm this by changing the NAs one at a time and trying to rerun the code.

A workaround is to create a dummy data.frame that gets considered first

```
df.0<-structure(list(a =rep(0,11),b=rep(0,11)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names =  2330:2340, class = "data.frame")
df.1<-structure(list(a = c(47.22, 88.89, 71.88, NA, 75, 100, 72.22, 
                       94.44, 52.78, 86.11, 66.67), b = c(46.88, 80.56, 80.56, NA, 31.25, 
                       100, 52.78, 100, 31.25, 91.67, 58.33)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = 2330:2340, class = "data.frame")

df.2<-structure(list(a = c(75, 47.22, 86.11, 93.75, 86.11, 77.78, 91.67, 
                           100, 38.89, 97.22, 100), b = c(71.88, 72.22, 83.33, NA, 50, 69.44, 
                            100, 100, 53.13, 91.67, 88.89)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = 2330:2340, class =   "data.frame")

pmax(df.0,df.1, df.2)
```